# Very long lines of input in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that performs some substitutions on the output of `mysqldump`.

The input can have very long lines (hundreds of MB), because a single line can represent a multi-row INSERT statement for all the data in a table. The `mysqldump` utility can be coerced to produce one INSERT statement per row, but I don't have control of every client.

My script naively expects `IO#each_line` to control memory usage:

```
$stdin.each_line do |line|
  next if options[:entity_excludes].any? { |entity| line =~ /^(DROP TABLE IF EXISTS|INSERT INTO) `custom_#{entity}(s|_meta)`/ }
  line.gsub!(/^CREATE TABLE `/, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `")
  line.gsub!('{{__OPF_SITEURL__}}', siteurl) if siteurl
  $stdout.write(line)
end
```

I've already seen input with maximum line length over 400MB, and this translates directly into process resident memory.

Are there libraries for Ruby that allow text transforms on an input stream using buffers instead of relying on line-delimited input?

This was marked as a duplicate of a [simpler question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581156/how-can-i-read-a-file-bytes-at-a-time-in-ruby). But there's quite a bit more to this. You need to keep track of multiple buffers and test for application of transforms even when they apply across a buffer boundary. It's easy to get wrong, which is why I'm hoping a library already exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I read a file, bytes at a time in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581156/how-can-i-read-a-file-bytes-at-a-time-in-ruby)

Comment: You can have a look at [IO#foreach](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO.foreach) - which does not read the entire file at once and provides each line of file.

Comment: @Surya The example code shows reading input one line at a time. The question is about a situation where one line at a time is too much, because of very long lines.

Comment: @sheldonh : If just changing the large line in a large file is the only end goal then probably look at `sed` command.